# A strange, but probably simple, shell_exec issue

Tags: php

If I run this command on the command line (on my Mac OS X):

```
echo -n "hello" > foo-cmd.txt
```

I get the expected result, namely a file `foo-cmd.txt` containing "`hello`" without any newline at the end.

However, if I run this PHP code:

```
<?php
shell_exec("echo -n \"hello\" > foo-php.txt");
?>
```

I get a file `foo-php.txt` containing the text "`-n hello`" followed by a newline! In other words, the argument `-n` sneaks in as output, instead of being treated as an argument!

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is using the shell's *built-in* version of `echo` which doesn't support the `-n` option.

Try `/bin/echo` instead.

Comment: How do you figure out (from system to system, or from one PHP version to another) whether shell_exec is using its own built-in version of a particular command?

Comment: @Enchilada it's not `shell_exec` that has the problem - it's the system shell that `shell_exec` invokes that has the built-ins.  The simple answer is, don't use `shell_exec` for something that could have been trivially done with a few lines of PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
shell_exec("echo\ -n \"hello\" > foo-php.txt");
```